# Why are media queries now working in this code example?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

whý is this media query not working?i want the div to become 300x300 and red when the viewport is more than 800px: expand it to full screen to watch the problem.

```css
.test{
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  background-color:grey;
}

@media (width: 800px){
  .test{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code, so that we can see what might be causing the problem and be able to help. External links can break or change over time and make the question invalid and unhelpful to future users. You can add a stack snippet using the `[<>]` button in the question editor to add the code in a runnable snippet.

Comment: it works fine but the media query will trigger only when the width of the screen is equal to 800px .. try to reduce your browser width slowly and you will get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the media query, you added an error by specifying `@media (width: 800px) {}`. You need to fix this - `@media (max-width: 800px){}`.

P.S. if you specify `@media (min-width: 800px){}` in the media query, then your red square will be displayed on large screens, and the gray square will appear at 800 pixels.

```css
.test{
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  background-color:grey;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
  .test{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```